# How can I CMake find the package which was compiled

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, exiv2

First of all I'm working with Centos 7
I'm trying to compile the latest darktable and I have overcome sveral problems, including compiling gphoto2, exiv2, etc.

But now when I try to build darktable using the basic instructions here:
https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable

> `mkdir build/
>   cd build/
>   cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/darktable/ ..
>   make
>   sudo make install`

Whilst trying cmake several times I had to solve a few depencies problems, but the one I'm stuck with is.

Centos7 comes with Exiv2 version 0.23, Darktable requires minimum version 0.24

I removed exiv2 0.23 with dnf and then successfully compiled and installed exiv2 from source to version 0.26.

After a few attempts I configured exiv2 with a **--prefix=/usr** as darktable said he could not find the libraries.

Now I still have the same problem
and cmake exits with the following error:

> `CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindExiv2.cmake:46 (message):
>     Exiv2 version check failed.  Version was found, at least version 0.24 is
>     required
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     src/CMakeLists.txt:292 (find_package)
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/opt/darktable-2.4.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also "/opt/darktable-2.4.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".`

My knowledge of cmake is next to nothing,but I see that src/CMakeLists.txt line 292 searches for a package which doesn't exist anymore, because I've removed it with dnf.

> `# Require exiv2 >= 0.24 to make sure everything we need is available
>   find_package(Exiv2 0.24 REQUIRED)
>   include_directories(SYSTEM ${Exiv2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
>   list(APPEND LIBS ${Exiv2_LIBRARIES})
>   add_definitions(${Exiv2_DEFINITIONS})`

But how can I make cmake look for the exiv2 I've build and installed?
And find all the libraries it needs?

## **Found The Solution!**

I realised that under the /usr/lib64/pkgconfig /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig and a few others a lot of ***.pc** files were.

After my compilation and installation of Exiv2 it placed this **exiv2.pc** under /usr/lib/pkgconfig/. And it was the only file there.

So I made a soft link in /usr/lib64/pkgconfig to the exiv2.pc file
and it did the job, just got another list of issues popping up.

Answer (score 1):

That CMake line looks for header files in `Exiv2_INCLUDE_DIRS` and for a library file `Exiv2_LIBRARIES`. Try setting those variables in the CMake command:

```
cmake [...] -DExiv2_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include -DExiv2_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib
```

(Maybe the latter need to be the library file itself, not its directory, I don't know.)

(The `[...]` is to be replaced with whatever arguments you already had there.)

Comment: Thanks Cris, I tried it but it didn't work, I think I'm getting closer but It's not fully working yet. I edited my inital question.